# How to override semantic highlighting in C++ Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, themes

I've been trying to create a vscode theme for a couple of weeks, and everything is working out pretty well, except that something called "Semantic Highlighting" keeps overriding my theme's configurations.

[image]

Now there are a lot of questions and solutions regarding this already, but none seem to make a difference. I like semantic highlighting, but there ARE some colors I would like to modify.

I couldn't find a way to "override" the semantic highlighting with my theme configurations, so I tried disabling it by:

`theme.json`: `"semanticHighlighting": false"`
and
`settings.json`: `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false"`

But none of them make a difference.

To keep it simple, I would like to keep semantic highlighting turned on (if possible) and just override some of its coloring with my theme's configurations. I don't want to mess with `"semanticTokenColors": {}` since my target scopes are really specific and `semanticTokenColors` only offer to modify a wide range of scopes such as `type`, `string`, `class`, etc...

Is there any way I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

**OS: Windows 11

Vscode Version: 1.73.1 Stable Build

Installed C++ Extensions:**

- [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)
- [C/C++ Advanced Lint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jbenden.c-cpp-flylint)
- [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
- [Better C++ Syntax](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax) (I've tried disabling this too.)
- [clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer. The problem is that some languages have "default overrides" for some settings; C++ overrides the general `semanticHighlighting` setting with it's own default (which is `true`), so you must disable it specifically for C++.